# How do I get a column in GridView to show its name that corresponds to its ID?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

Ive got a GridView connected to an SQL data source that I want to display as home and away team names. Instead I can only retrieve their `Home_Team_ID` and `Away_Team_ID` as these match their `Team_ID that is stored in another table. I've tried "Bind("Team_name")" but this returns the first team name in the`Team` table for both sides. How do I fix this?
[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="EnterMatchGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Team_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnRowDataBound="EnterMatchGridView_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Home_team_ID" SortExpression="Home_team_ID">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_team_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Home_team_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Away_team_ID" SortExpression="Away_team_ID">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Away_team_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Away_team_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Home_team_score" HeaderText="Home_team_score" SortExpression="Home_team_score" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Away_team_score" HeaderText="Away_team_score" SortExpression="Away_team_score" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Game_date" SortExpression="Game_date">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Game_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Game_date") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SportsData2ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT MatchStatistics.Home_team_ID, MatchStatistics.Away_team_ID, MatchStatistics.Home_team_score, MatchStatistics.Away_team_score, MatchStatistics.Game_date, Team.Team_ID, Team.Team_name FROM MatchStatistics INNER JOIN Team ON (MatchStatistics.Home_team_ID = Team.Team_ID OR MatchStatistics.Away_team_ID = Team.Team_ID) AND MatchStatistics.Home_team_ID = Team.Team_ID WHERE (Team.Team_ID = @Team_ID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HomeFormDDL" Name="Team_ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Where each home and away team column says their ID (in this case 8 and 32) I want to replace these with their corresponding `Team_IDs`e.g. Aston Villa and Norwich have `Team_ID` 8 and 32 respectively.

Comment: So instead of, say, displaying `8`, you want to display 'Dodgers` or something?

Comment: Yes! The ID for home and away teams match the Team_ID since they are foreign keys.

Comment: What does your SQL query look like that you use to generate your data? Also, could you provide a sample of just the data that gets loaded into the grid? You should be able to bind the column that contains the team name in exactly the same way it is bound for the id, assuming the data is correct, that is.

Comment: See my updated answer, I had to guess at your table structure, but you should be able to figure it out from that I think.

Comment: Didn't work for my database design, I've updated my question with the tables relevant.

Comment: How are the relationships defined, you would want to access the team name via the relationship. Take a look here for how to access child relationships: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.childrelations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Added another update to go with your DataTables setup.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to set the `HeaderText` of the columns.

```
foreach(var col in EnterMatchGridView.Columns)
{
   col.HeaderText = "Some Text";
}
```

Granted the above example is not exactly what you want, but it does show how to access it. If you look above in your ASP code, you will see the `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Away_team_ID" ...>` you can modify it right there if you don't need to set it through code.

You can also bind something to that property if you want too.

After clarification, you should ensure that your SQL query is selecting the data properly. Without knowing your table structures I can only guess, but you may want something like:

```
select t1.home_team_id, t2.team_name as home_team_name, 
       t1.away_team_id, t3.team_name as away_team_name, 
       t1.home_team_score, t1.away_team_score, t1.game_date
from game_table t1
join team_table t2
on t2.team_id = t1.home_team_id
join team_table t3
on t3.team_id = t1.away_team_id;
```

Then you can bind on `home_team_name` and `away_team_name` on your columns.

Using DataTables, as described above, you should be able to do the following, then bind to `results` as your datatable:

```
DataTable games = new DataTable()
games.Columns.Add("Home_Team_ID", typeof(int));
games.Columns.Add("Home_Team_Name", typeof(string));
games.Columns.Add("Away_Team_ID", typeof(int));
games.Columns.Add("Away_Team_Name", typeof(string));
games.Columns.Add("Home_Team_Score", typeof(int));
games.Columns.Add("Away_Team_Score", typeof(int));
games.Columns.Add("Game_Date", typeof(DateTime));

var results = from dataRows1 in MatchStatistics.AsEnumerable()
              join dataRows2 in Teams.AsEnumerable()
              on dataRows1.Field<int>("Home_Team_ID") equals dataRows2.Field<int>("Team_ID") 
              join dataRows3 in Teams.AsEnumerable()
              on dataRows1.Field<int>("Away_Team_ID") equals dataRows3.Field<int("Team_ID")
              select games.LoadDataRow(new object[]
              {
                  dataRows1.Field<int>("Home_Team_ID"),
                  dataRows2.Field<string>("Team_Name"),
                  dataRows1.Field<int>("Away_Team_ID"),
                  dataRows3.Field<string>("Team_Name"),
                  dataRows1.Field<int>("Home_Team_Score"),
                  dataRows1.Field<int>("Away_Team_Score"),
                  dataRows1.Field<DateTime>("Game_Date")
              }, false);
```

Ultimately, what it comes down to is that you need to access the `Teams` DataTable using the relationship, you can't access just the table by itself unless you filter your results by the `Team_ID`, otherwise you will just get the first item, or all of the items in the DataTable.

Comment: The headers aren't the problem, I just need the ID's to display their corresponding names

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide a sample of what you want your grid to look like? It isn't very clear what you want. Try to provide a simpel example of how you want the grid to look, and how it looks currently, i.e. `Column1   | Column2  | Column3` <new line> `======================` <new line> 'value1     | value2     | value3` - etc... but obviously formatted properly. Just so we can get an idea of what you are expecting.